# Alternative for Flutter Tap/Button component that have great responsiveness/sensitiveness?

Tags: flutter

In my application I use inkwell/flat button/ink response/Gesture Detector/RaisedButton, etc for my tap component. The application already in release Alpha channel (Android) and Test Flight (IOS). However the user is not satisfied with the result, because all the button is less responsive/sensitive compare to native button component (Android/iOS). Is there any alternative or another way in Flutter to create tapable widget or button that have responsiveness similar with native application?

Example code:

```
InkWell(
      onTap: () => Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(
          Routes.MEMBERSHIP,
          arguments: membershipPlanModel),
      child: Card(
          margin: EdgeInsets.only(
            right: 16,
          ),
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10))),
          child: Container(...
```

Another code:

```
 FlatButton(
           onPressed: () async {
           _cancelTransaction();
           Navigator.of(context).pop(true);
           Navigator.of(context).pop(true);
           },
           child: Text(
            Labels.YES,
            style: Fonts.GHOST,
            ),
           ),
```

Comment: By responsiveness what do you mean? Button has to be more sensitive to tap, or have bigger tap area?

Comment: Have you tried running the app in release mode? Flutter's debug mode is often slow and unresponsive

Comment: Yes, the sensitivity of the tap, not the tap area. The user said sometimes the button/tap widget is responsive (respond to the tap), sometimes not if user tap the button/widget softly. Actually the app already in the release mode both Android and IOS